# Is there a configuration-automator-with-macro-substitutions tool? Or could someone help me narrow this down?

Tags: xml, automation

I'm looking for a basic automation tool; I don't know whether it doesn't exist, or if all of my google searches are still too generic. What I would like to do is start with a template file `file.in` and generate a target file `file.out` by running a tool (script?) to replace all occurrences of certain substitution strings with their definitions in a macro file `macros.txt`. More concretely, the macros file would contain entries like

```
PATH = /Users/me/mypath/...
```

And the template file would contain text like

```
"... change the working directory to @PATH@ and ... "
```

At the moment I'm accomplishing what I need by using CMake's `configure_file()`, but that seems too heavy handed for the task at hand. Ultimately the target files will be XML documents where I need to populate a few fields with configuration-dependent information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, SO just informed me that this question won me the Tumbleweed badge. I decided to roll my own solution, which amounted to about 10 lines of Python.